# Debug this Yup validation with the .when() method using the .matches() method

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I'm having trouble with Yup validations and using the **.when()** method with a **.matches()** regex condition.

I'm not sure if this implementation is correct, Yups documentation mentions that the matcher function can be used with the .when() method but there are no examples I can find and I am running into this error when implementing the code in this way:

```
Error: Cyclic dependency, node was:"description"
```

Here is my code, I am trying to adjust the max length based on whether or not a dash is included in the input string:

```
export default Yup.object().shape({
  description: Yup.string()
    .matches(
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/,
      'Description can only contain letters, numbers and dashes'
    )
    .when('description', {
      is: (val) => val == /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/,
      then: Yup.string().max(15, 'max length is 15'), // maxlength 15
      otherwise: Yup.string().max(14, 'max length is 14') // maxlength 14
    }),
});
```

Here is a link to the documentation I've been viewing:

https://github.com/jquense/yup

I'm trying to figure out how to adjust my code so that the error goes away and the validation works as intended.  If there is a dash in the input string the user enters, the max length should be 15, otherwise, it should be 14.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean instead of .when('description'), {...}, replace .when() with .test() ?

Comment: Test has value of current field

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
description: yup.string().when([], (v, { originalValue }) => 
   originalValue.description == /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/ ? Yup.string().max(15, 'max length is 15') : Yup.string().max(14, 'max length is 14')
)
```

Comment: Close, it appears as though the validation does not switch between a max of 15 and 14, the validation is always validation for a max length of 14